# No resource found that matches the given name (with value @xml/shortcuts) in Manifest

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I'm getting an error like this when i'm trying to compile a Xamarin Android Project

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/shortcuts')

This happens in AndroidManifest.xml,

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="md52124032e3d2852089d609a424068def2.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
```

and when i try to remove that specific line it just resurfaces once i build it

any inputs would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Have u created `shortcuts.xml` file in  `xml` folder in `res` directory

Comment: @NileshRathod i had, but i've removed the folder and the code, not sure why it still needs it though

Comment: so just remove the `meta-data` from your manifest

Comment: Firstly,you  android:targetSdkVersion is 25 or higer, you also could try to regist this shortcuts above the activity`[Activity(Label = "AppShortcuts", MainLauncher = true)]
 [MetaData("android.app.shortcuts", Resource = "@xml/shortcuts")]
 public class Main : ListActivity, View.IOnClickListener` ,you could refer to this blog about shortcut:https://blog.xamarin.com/simple-and-intuitive-app-shortcuts-in-android-7-1/